# react-native-camera selecting image and video from library(gallery)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

i am using react-native-camera in my app.
What i want is to be able to select photos and videos from gallery.

`<View>
  <Text onpress={}>Library</Text>
</View>`

If i click on library My phone's library should open containing all images and videos in my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Actually its not possible with react native camera.
So i switched back to ImagePicker and set mediaType:'mixed'(only for ios).
However i had to add a change in ImagePickerManager.m. I added

`|| [[self.options objectForKey:@"mediaType"] isEqualToString:@"mixed"]`

in the if condition which previously looked like

`if ([[self.options objectForKey:@"mediaType"] isEqualToString:@"video"])`

and it did the trick

Sorry i had to add below code in place of else block of above if

```swift
if ([[self.options objectForKey:@"mediaType"] isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
    self.picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
} else if ([[self.options objectForKey:@"mediaType"] isEqualToString:@"mixed"]) {
    self.picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
} else {
    self.picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different package: [React-Native-Image-Picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker).

React-Native-Camera is for **recording** pictures/videos.

Comment: But i have to use camera for clicking photos and need to access library for photos and videos. Image Picker only allows to pick photos from library

Comment: So just use both?

Comment: I have switched to Image Picker again and using mediaType option, when i set it to video it shows video but when i set it to mixed its still showing images only